# get previous command's argments inside zsh script

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to develop a function in bash that will open a file in vim after I've ran the cat script in the terminal.

```sh
cat readme.txt
```

now, I want to open the file in vim. Instead of writing `vim readme.txt`, I want to create a function `vv` that will get the the last commands arguments (`!*`), and prepend `vim` to it.

```sh
function vv() {
    args=$(!*)
    vim $args
}
```

I've also tried setting as alias:

```sh
alias vv="vim !*"
```

Both of these won't work. Is there any way that I can get previous command's argment inside the zsh script?

Answer (score 0):

You need not `!*` but `!$`. That's for bash, in zsh it's same i think

Comment: Hm, I've checked and thats work but try `!!:$` also

Answer (score 0):

If the last argument is sufficient, you can use `$_`:

```
vv() {
  vim "$_"
}
```

If you run `ls -l foo.txt`, then `vv` will run `vim foo.txt`

(If the last argument is *not* sufficient, then this will not help)